# One to One Relationship With Same Entity Type - FluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Just a little concern on how to configure EF for a one to one relationship with same Entity which is a rare case for me. This requirement came to me and i was a bit skeptical on how to model this.

Here is the scenario,

A patient can have one partner and a partner can only belong to one patient. A partner is also a patient.

I have my model like this;

```
 public class Patient
 {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public EGender Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public long PartnerId { get; set; }

    public Patient Partner { get; set; }

    public EPatientType PatientType { get; set; }
 }
```

And my FluentAPI config like this, but not sure i got this right

```
      builder.HasOne(p => p.Partner)
            .WithOne(p => p.Partner) // Not sure what to do here
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasForeignKey<Patient>(p => p.PartnerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Any idea on how to model this on fluentAPI or how to proceed is appreciated...

Comment: Just `OwnsOne` without argument will suffice. Is this Ef core or the full version?

Comment: This is EF Core.

Comment: @Mat ...are you saying that I would do builder.OwnsOne(x =>x.Partner) ??

Comment: Sorry, I mean, `builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Partner).HasOne()` probably will work. When we dont have navigation property for one end, we just configure it without specifying the property. But not sure if a one on one will work for same table, because, one-on-one implies the child will also have same id as the parent. Not sure how its in Ef core.

Comment: @Mat ...I think HasOne() would need a parameter as well...this cannot be empty. But again, this boils down to where I'm coming from ....I.e how to model this right.

Answer (score 0):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
        .HasOne(a => a.Partner)
        .WithOne(b => b.Patient)
        .HasForeignKey<Patient>(b => b.PartnerId)
        .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: i think PartnerId can be null and for this need to nullable it and if add index in this property can be to unique it

Comment: Yes...I know the partnerId should accept null value.  The problem is setting up the one to one relationship ship. I don't know if I'm right or wrong on the place I made a comment. On the reverse side of the relationship I.e withOne()...how do I handle that with same entity. Because normally...I have to reference another entity if it's a one to one with two different entities.

Comment: my answer update it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
builder.HasOne(p => p.Partner)
       .WithOne()
       .IsRequired(false)
       .HasForeignKey<Patient>(p => p.PartnerId);
```

It worked for me.